# Gap between the elements in Lightning component when it renders

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-design-system, slds

It might sound like a silly question but I came across something while creating a Lightning component. Please have a look into my component and help me clear my doubts that is mentioned below.

Below is my component code:-

```
<aura:component controller="ContactListController">
    <aura:attribute name="contactList" type="list"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInitialization}"/>
    <div class="slds-p-around_medium">
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.contactList}" var="singleContact">
        <lightning:card footer="{!singleContact.Phone}" title="{!singleContact.Name}" 
                        iconName="standard:contact_list">
            <b>First Name</b> : {!singleContact.FirstName}<br></br>
            <b>Last Name</b> : {!singleContact.LastName}<br></br>
            <b>Email</b> : {!singleContact.Email}
        </lightning:card>   
    </aura:iteration>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

Now if you see in the above code, I have put the `<div>` tag for padding outside the `<aura:iteration>` and I get the result like this:-

[image: Less Spacing]

As you can see there is less spacing between two lightning cards.But when i put my `<div>` tag inside the `<aura:iteration>` then there is more space between the lightning cards.

[image: More Spacing]

I am not able to get why this is happening so?

Thanks in Advance,
Ali

Answer (score 3):

If you want some space left between the cards, you can use margin class like added below(depending on your need either you can make it less or more) -

For doing less(try this ) - `slds-m-top-xxx-small`
For doing More(try this ) - `slds-m-top-x-small` or `slds-m-top-small` or `slds-m-top-medium`

```html
<aura:component controller="ContactListController">
    <aura:attribute name="contactList" type="list"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInitialization}"/>
    <div class="slds-p-around_medium">
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.contactList}" var="singleContact">
        <lightning:card footer="{!singleContact.Phone}" title="{!singleContact.Name}" 
                        iconName="standard:contact_list" class="slds-m-top_xx-small" >
            <b>First Name</b> : {!singleContact.FirstName}<br></br>
            <b>Last Name</b> : {!singleContact.LastName}<br></br>
            <b>Email</b> : {!singleContact.Email}
        </lightning:card>   
    </aura:iteration>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is my understanding :-

It's because of the CSS class slds-p-around_medium. This adds padding around the div. If that div is inside the iteration, the padding repeats itself. If it's outside the iteration, I only get one padded div.